# Stop scheduling pods on kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes

For testing purpose, I have enabled pod scheduling on kubernetes master node with the following command

`kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`

Now I have added worker node to the cluster and I would like to stop scheduling pods on master. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply taint the node again.

```
kubectl taint nodes master node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule
```

Comment: I used the same command but there is an error: kubectl taint nodes master node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule
Error from server (NotFound): nodes "master" not found

Comment: You should replace <MASTERNODENAME> in command -- >
"kubectl taint nodes <MASTERNODENAME> node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule"
Also you can see all nodes schedule status by -->
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {.spec.taints[?(@.effect=='NoSchedule')].effect}{\"\n\"}{end}"

Answer (score 2):

Taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. One or more taints are applied to a node; this marks that the node should not accept any pods that do not tolerate the taints. Tolerations are applied to pods, and allow (but do not require) the pods to schedule onto nodes with matching taints.

Even placed a taint on Master node,you can specify a toleration for a pod in the PodSpec, the pod  would be able to schedule onto Master node:

```
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
```

To learn more,see [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)